# SE.com "All Sites" logo wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The [All Sites page on stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com/sites) still has the wrong logo for our site.  The talk bubble color seems right, the logo just hasn't been updated yet.

[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com